# to merge 3 tables email field n check for existence of d same mail in registered user table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

I want to merge 3 tables together and each has field named as email,all three tables emails has to merge in a single column and then this email need to check against registered user table for their existence.If existed then show all mail which are existing.i have tried but not getting a workable solution.

**edit** - editor attempted to reconstruct code from comments; looks like some things were lost.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weekone.Email),
         GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weektwo.Email), 
         GROUP_CONCAT(participants.Email) FROM luckydraw_weekone 
         LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id 
         LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id"; 

  query for mergingtd>"; // and all details you want to add 
  $display_string_user .= "</tr>"; 
  } 
}
$display_string .= "</table>"; 
$display_string_user .= "</table>"; 
echo $display_string; 
echo $display_string_user;

$query2 = "SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail='.$row[0].' OR mail='.$row[1].' OR mail='.$row[2].'";
```

First query is to merge the three tables; and second one is to check for existing emails in user table. The second one is inside the while loop.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? This ought to be simple, but maybe there is a twist. What does "not getting a workable solution" mean - are you getting nothing, missing some emails, getting duplicates, ...?

Comment: yes getting duplicate emails

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weekone.Email),GROUP_CONCAT(luckydraw_weektwo.Email), GROUP_CONCAT(participants.Email) FROM luckydraw_weekone LEFT JOIN luckydraw_weektwo ON luckydraw_weekone.id = luckydraw_weektwo.id LEFT JOIN participants ON luckydraw_weekone.id = participants.id";
 query for mergingtd>"; 
 // and all details you want to add
 $display_string_user .= "</tr>"; 
  }
  } 
  $display_string .= "</table>"; 
  $display_string_user .= "</table>"; 
  echo $display_string;
  echo $display_string_user;

Comment: $query2 = "SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail='.$row[0].' OR mail='.$row[1].' OR mail='.$row[2].'";

Comment: first  query is to merge the thre tables

Comment: and second one is to check for existing emails in user table

Comment: secon one is inside the while loop.

Comment: You can use the `edit` link under the question to paste your attempt into the question itself; this will allow much better formatting and will make more sense for everyone who reads this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.mail
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT email FROM luckydraw_weekone
            UNION 
            SELECT email FROM luckydraw_weektwo
            UNION 
            SELECT email FROM participants
          ) AS A ON u.mail = A.email;
```

Comment: Ah... the `DISTINCT` keyword. That should help.

Comment: @user3172127 You're most welcome. Take a tour of Stackoverflow on http://stackoverflow.com/tour.